# INSERT INTO Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am a newbie to Visual Studio 2010, so there may be a very silly syntax error in my code. So, please do not downvote my question. I have the database correct and the name of the table is Contacts. I want to insert into the table (Columns - First Name and Last Name) with values. Now, something is going wrong in my code. The error that is being shown is
`{"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."}` . Please check out my code. It is given below.

```
 Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data    
 Source=C:\Users\Rajesh\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project 
 \Contacts.accdb")

    Conn.Open()

    Dim Cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Cmd.Connection = Conn
    Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Contacts (First Name, Last Name)  
    Values('Bruce','Lee')"
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Conn.Close()
```

Any help of course will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need square brackets around column names because they contain spaces:

```
INSERT INTO Contacts ([First Name], [Last Name]) Values('Bruce','Lee')
```

Comment: Thanks buddy...your answer was greatly helpful to me...thou art awesome. An upvote from me.